# Chrome canvas 2d context measureText giving me weird results

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, canvas

Here's a compact version of my problem

```js
let canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
ctx.font = '11pt Calibri'
ctx.fillStyle = '#000000'
let temp = ctx.font
console.log(ctx.font)
console.log(ctx.measureText('M').width)
ctx.font = 'bold ' + ctx.font
console.log(ctx.font)
console.log(ctx.measureText('M').width)
ctx.font = 'italic ' + ctx.font
console.log(ctx.font)
console.log(ctx.measureText('M').width)
ctx.font = temp
console.log(ctx.font)
console.log(ctx.measureText('M').width)
```

Running this code in chrome produces incorrect numbers, at least at the end. First I'm setting the font to '11pt Calibri', but chrome immediately changes it to '15px Calibri' for some reason, and because of that it's producing text that's slightly bigger than correct. I read that the canvas runs at 96dpi so the correct px should be 14.6.

After that, I'm measuring the width of a text M, which comes out at 12.53401184 for me, this number is important.

After that, I've modified the font to add bold and italic, and then I roll it back to what the font originally was. Now when I measure it, it gives me 12.824707, which is a massive 0.3px off. I'm drawing text on a canvas with anywhere from 600px to 800px width, and I need it to wrap correctly, so I need it to be precise to 1px over the line, so individual letters need to have at least 0.02px accuracy, which worked decently until I started using bolds and italics.

None of the above problems exist on firefox, and disabling canvas hardware acceleration on chrome doesn't seem to have any effect. I'm using chrome 52.0 which is the current latest version.

Edit: I figured out you don't even need to do any of that to get the incorrect number, simply doing this is enough.

```js
let canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
ctx.font = '11pt Calibri'
ctx.fillStyle = '#000000'

console.log(ctx.font)
console.log(ctx.measureText('M').width)
let temp = ctx.font
ctx.font = temp
console.log(ctx.font)
console.log(ctx.measureText('M').width)
```

Comment: Well I think you've got everything to fill a bug report to chrome. They are transforming on the fly the font-size unit to `px`  while they shouldn't, and since they don't use floating values for this `px` unit, it generates this issue, but you already know that.

Comment: Ok I will do that, just wanted to make sure I didn't miss something obvious.

Comment: No I think it's a bad implementation, in FF, they do allow floating values for `px` unit too.

Comment: Just in case -- a probable workaround would be to try to use an ordinary HTML span to measure the text. Simply position it absolute, set `visibility: hidden` and `font` style property as needed, set `contentText` property to the text value for measuring and then call `span.getBoundingClientRect().width`, it seems to give accurate floating-point pixel values in Chrome.

Comment: Ok I submitted the bug report. Also Andrew, do I need to add the span to the DOM for it to work?

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=635427

Answer (score 4):

### **Don't use "pt" for font sizing on canvas.**

**CSS Absolute and Magic Units**

Using `pt` for font sizing is [not recommended](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html#font-size) as it has no real meaning for media that represent visual information in terms of pixels (discrete indivisible image units) and is displayed on screens which have no fixed pixel density.

`pt` is an absolute measuring unit, the same as `cm` while `px` is a "magic unit" and only ever has an absolute meaning when the media type is print.

> OP: "I read that the canvas runs at 96dpi so the correct px should be 14.6."

This is not correct the canvas does not have a absolute measuring unit. A pixel as a CSS unit only has an absolute dimension when the media type is print in which case 1px = 1/96 of an inch. The canvas is not considered as a printed media.

---

### **Why does the Width change?**

**The apparent problem**

```
ctx.font = '11pt Calibri'
console.log(ctx.font);                   // 15px Calibri
console.log(ctx.measureText('M').width); // 12.534011840820312
ctx.font = ctx.font
console.log(ctx.font);                   // 15px Calibri
console.log(ctx.measureText('M').width); // 12.82470703125
```

Though the `ctx.font` values are the same the measured font widths are different

**The simple solution**

```
ctx.font = ctx.font = '11pt Calibri';
```

Will avoid the measured size discrepancies, but i am sure that nobody would consider this as anything but an ugly work around to an "apparent" browser specific bug.

**The solution**

Don't use `pt` units when setting canvas fonts.

**What is going on.**

The issue is a misunderstanding of what the `ctx.font` property actually is. It does not represent the current font's actual internal representation but rather an abstract human readable form.

> [W3C 2D Canvas](https://www.w3.org/TR/2dcontext/#text-styles): "On getting, the font attribute must return the **serialized form** of the current font of the context."

The process of serialization will lose precision. [Serialising CSS values](https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-1/#serializing-css-values).The W3C standard specifies that the `font-size` be in `px` units which in this case further amplifies the apparent "bug"

The `font` properties set function takes the CSS font string, parses it. If valid then sets the canvas internal font and writes the serialized CSS font value to `context.font` The two do not have to match and the standard does not specify that they should.

---

### **Summary**

The behaviour as described in the question is not a "bug". Inconsistency between browsers though (as always) is a concern. If we are to follow the standards, one could consider that browsers not showing the measurement inconsistency have interpreted the standard incorrectly and filled a ambiguity with their own interpretation (though this is speculative on my part).

The simple solution to the problem is to follow the standard's guidelines and not use `pt` when setting `font-size` values for anything but printed media.

As with all computer media "dpi" only ever has meaning when printing and is not defined until then. Nor do pixels necessarily equate to dots when printing. Always use resolution when referring to pixels rather than `dp1` (my pet hate)

Comment: The behavior depicted in the question is a bug. Chrome does set the font size to some length but the returned string is not the same as what it is set to. I would be fine if they wanted to convert to px, but then the getter should reflect the exact value that it's set to. Either they do the rounding directly when the value is set, either they do output the real floating value on the getter, either it's a bug.

Comment: Also OP has found this behavior on pt but the exact same applies for em and floating px.

Comment: Pps: according to your link serializing css, section length and number, they should return a base 10 number, with maximum 6 decimals precision.

Comment: @Kaiido Neither Chrome or Firefox convert `11pt  Calibri` to the correct  px value. `11pt = 0.15278"` , `15px = 0.15625"` , `11pt = 14.667px` and `15px = 11.25pt`  It is Firefox that has the non standard value as it sets the ctx.font value to `11pt Calibri` though the standard clearly states it should be in px

Comment: No, it talks about css pixels, to differentiate with the canvas pixels, but it doesn't say nowhere it should default to the px unit. I'm not saying FF implementation is the correct one, and we all know that text styles implementations's concistency in canvas are like the worth thing UAs have made, but all the link you do provide in your answer go against chrome. If they really have to parse the font just like css, then they should allow floating values, with a precision of 6 decimals. They don't, it's a bug.

Comment: @Kaiido from  W3C 2D canvas doc "...with the 'font-size' component converted to CSS pixels"  referring to the ctx.font property value. They dont its a bug. So what. I have yet to find anything on serialising px vals apart from the link I provided. I am not satisfied that that is whole story. There is no chrome bug report regarding this and its not something that would be missed. FF is clearly not following the standard by not converting to px and until I see  unambiguously doc for serialisation of a CSS px I cant say Chrome has a bug or not. Both display the correct font size

Comment: What I'm doing does involve printed media, including simulating real world paper and font sizes, and I've been getting very correct results by assuming 96dpi for the canvas and using only inches as the base values for paper and deriving everything else from it, that is until I started modifying the font value. If I have to use px instead of font, I will, but chrome doesn't accept 14.666666px Calibri as the font string and turns it into 15px Calibri anyway but Firefox gives 100% the same results between 11pt Calibri and 14.666666px Calibri.

Comment: Once again, I think you get confused by this "CSS pixels". This is not exactly the same as the `px` unit in this context. It's just a remainder to UAs that they have to take the [CSS pixels rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values/#absolute-lengths) to make the calculations instead of physical pixels.

Comment: @orchlonBatsaikhan Just ignore the value in the context.font property. Both chrome and FF set the font size correctly you only get a problem when you try to use that value to set the font. Keep the font as a separate value and think of context.font as write only and you will not have any problems

Answer (score 2):

I realized why it's broken. Chrome does something internally to compensate for pt values, even though the font gets highjacked to 15px. So when I get the font value from the ctx.font to modify it, I'm getting the modified px value, instead of the original pt so I'm actually giving it a raw 15px value, so when this happens chrome doesn't compensate. A workaround is to keep the original font somewhere else, like ctx.originalFont and then use it for modifying instead of ctx.font

For example this works

```js
let canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
ctx.font = '11pt Calibri'
ctx.originalFont = '11pt Calibri'
ctx.fillStyle = '#000000'

console.log(ctx.font)
console.log(ctx.measureText('M').width)
let temp = ctx.originalFont
ctx.font = temp
console.log(ctx.font)
console.log(ctx.measureText('M').width)
```